# MacOS Apple Maps: Can I show street numbers?

Tags: macos, maps

I might mention that I am in Melbourne, Australia, so it’s possible that the answer might be affected by my location.

Is it possible to show the street numbers on the Maps app?

Answer (score 1):

Drop a pin on the street and Apple Maps shows it’s best guess as to the street address. Same for just entering a street address - maps will pin where it thinks that is.

[image: Apple Maps detail in VIC, AU]

A quick check of one of the suburbs near Melbourne shows this data to be equivalent for you as for us in the US. It’s not perfect, as I would expect this pin to be in Ervin Rd.